# How to retrieve the realmID from callbacks to the AppURL

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

When you are in `QuickBooks Online` and navigate back to your App via the blue dot menu, this makes a callback to the AppURL.

However, we're not seeing the `realmID` passed anywhere in the callback.  Because of this we can't determine which account made the callback.

Is there something obvious that we're missing - where should the realmID be?

Answer (score 1):

The realmID is not passed back to the callback URL directly.  The callback URL needs to implement OpenID to talk to Intuit's provider service and request the realm.  Please note that the realm can only be fetched through OpenID when it is connected to the application.
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0010_getting_started/0030_integrate_your_app/0030_signing_into_and_out_of_intuit_from_within_your_app/sign-in/implement_sso_and_openid_in_your_app

Comment: Hi Peter,can you please give simple example on how to fetched realm id through Opendid?